# CheckBox in C# Windows App

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes and I am able to turn two of them off if one is checked. But I want that if the 3rd one is checked then the first two should be turned off. how can I do that?

This is what I am trying.

```
private void chkResFoodVeg_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //disables the other checkbox if one is checked
    this.chkResFoodNveg.Enabled = !this.chkResFoodVeg.Checked;
}

private void chkResFoodNveg_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.chkResFoodVeg.Enabled = !this.chkResFoodNveg.Checked;
}

private void chkResFoodBoth_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.chkResFoodBoth.Enabled = !this.chkResFoodNveg.Checked &&
   !this.chkResFoodVeg.Checked;
}
```

The last part of code doesn't work. It should turn off the first two checkboxes.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you actually just want to use radio buttons?

Comment: Use the Click() method on these instead.  Or do as @RyanCavanaugh has suggested, and use radio buttons, since it appears you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you
I will use the Radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is backwards, you need two assignments not combine the inputs.

```
private void chkResFoodBoth_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.chkResFoodNveg.Enabled = !this.chkResFoodBot.Checked;
    this.chkResFoodVeg.Enabled = !this.chkResFoodBot.Checked;
}
```

However, from how you are describing your buttons actions, it sounds like you are trying to emulate the behavior of a [RadioButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx), perhaps you should use that instead. It will only let you choose one of the 3 options at a time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for the [RadioButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx)! Although it is possible to implement what you want using the [CheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.aspx) - it's likely the wrong tool for this job.

Adding these to a Windows Form automatically implements the functionality that you want as long as they belong to the same container object like a [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx) or [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx).

[image: Example of Radio Buttons in use]